# Why do C++ stream manipulators not have a call operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, manipulators

I was wondering: if  for example `std::endl` is a regular function, then why does it lack the call operator (the `operator()`)?

i know that it is designed to be used with the the insertion (`<<`) and extraction (`>>`) operators. I tried to call it like this:

```
std::endl.();
```

But of course that didn't work.

Comment: Functions don't have "call operators". Only classes do. Functions can be called because that's part of the core language. `printf` also doesn't have a call operator.

Comment: What do you expect when calling `std::endl()` ?

Comment: Totally not an answer, but if you *were* trying to spell the function call operator, and if it existed, it would be spelled: `std::endl.operator()(args);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::endl` is just an ordinary function (or rather, function template) that you can call. You just have to call it with the correct argument:

```
std::endl(std::cout);    // OK, equivalent to "std::cout << std::endl;"
```

That's because the `ostream` overloads the shift operator for function pointers, in a manner equivalent to the following:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, ostream & (*f)(ostream &))
{
    return f(os);
}
```

(It will actually be a template for `basic_ostream` to deal with any kind of character traits and allocators.)